# How do you launch (start) the Voice recorder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

How do you launch the Voice recorder in Windows 10?

Comment: Like anything else in W10, type "recorder" into the start menu search bar.

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though it's now been renamed **Voice Recorder** in Windows 10.

Click the Start Menu button or Windows Key, and enter "Voice Recorder" into the search box. You should see it displayed as an application you can launch.